# Checking CharacterSet for single UnicodeScalar yields strange behaviour

Tags: swift, foundation, character-set

While working with `CharacterSet` I've come across an interesting problem. From what I have gathered so far `CharacterSet` is based around `UnicodeScalar`; you can initialise it with scalars and check if a scalar is contained within the set. Querying the set to find out if it contains a `Character`, who's glyph could be composed of several unicode scalar values, doesn't make sense.

My problem lies when I test with the  emoji, which is a single unicode scalar value (128518 in decimal). As this is a single unicode scalar value I would have thought it would work, and here are the results:

```
"" == UnicodeScalar(128518)! // true

// A few variations to show exactly what is being set up
let supersetA = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "")
let supersetB = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "A")
let supersetC = CharacterSet(charactersIn: UnicodeScalar(128518)!...UnicodeScalar(128518)!)
let supersetD = CharacterSet(charactersIn: UnicodeScalar(65)...UnicodeScalar(65)).union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: UnicodeScalar(128518)!...UnicodeScalar(128518)!))

supersetA.contains(UnicodeScalar(128518)!) // true
supersetB.contains(UnicodeScalar(128518)!) // false
supersetC.contains(UnicodeScalar(128518)!) // true
supersetD.contains(UnicodeScalar(128518)!) // false
```

As you can see, the check works if the `CharacterSet` contains a single scalar value (perhaps due to an optimisation) but in any other circumstance it doesn't work as expected.

I cannot find any information about the lower level implementation of `CharacterSet` or whether it works in a certain encoding (i.e. UTF-16 like `NSString`), but as the API deals a lot with `UnicodeScalar` I'm surprised it's failing like this, and I'm unsure as to why it's happening, or how to investigate further.

Can anyone shed any light on why this may be?

Comment: Seems to be some bugs of Foundation (or Swift Standard Library). The `supersetD` case returns `true` with Xcode 9, so the bug of `union(_:)` seems to be fixed in the latest SDKs. Workaround: `CharacterSet(charactersIn: "").union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "A"))`.

Comment: And it gets weirder: https://pastebin.com/zCrM1XUL. I did some digging and you might want to look at `_CFCharacterSetIsLongCharacterMember` in `CFCharacterSet.c`, that's what the contains method does (and I'm pretty sure I don't understand much of it ). https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/d95964015bed377baa99c3612281afa11bf06990/CoreFoundation/String.subproj/CFCharacterSet.c#L1716

Comment: @nyg I spent a bunch of time figuring out what it all does, so if you're curious, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source code to `CharacterSet` [is available, actually.](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4654a230fb67fc8ba34348c1f5f3758292223260/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/CharacterSet.swift) The source for `contains` is:

```
fileprivate func contains(_ member: Unicode.Scalar) -> Bool {
    switch _backing {
    case .immutable(let cs):
        return CFCharacterSetIsLongCharacterMember(cs, member.value)
    case .mutable(let cs):
        return CFCharacterSetIsLongCharacterMember(cs, member.value)
    }
}
```

So it basically just calls through to `CFCharacterSetIsLongCharacterMember`. The source code for that [is also available, although only for Yosemite](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFCharacterSet.c.auto.html) (the versions for El Cap and Sierra both say "Coming Soon"). However, the Yosemite code seemed to match what I was seeing in the disassembly on Sierra. Anyway, the code for that looks like this:

```
Boolean CFCharacterSetIsLongCharacterMember(CFCharacterSetRef theSet, UTF32Char theChar) {
    CFIndex length;
    UInt32 plane = (theChar >> 16);
    Boolean isAnnexInverted = false;
    Boolean isInverted;
    Boolean result = false;

    CF_OBJC_FUNCDISPATCHV(__kCFCharacterSetTypeID, Boolean, (NSCharacterSet *)theSet, longCharacterIsMember:(UTF32Char)theChar);

    __CFGenericValidateType(theSet, __kCFCharacterSetTypeID);

    if (plane) {
        CFCharacterSetRef annexPlane;

        if (__CFCSetIsBuiltin(theSet)) {
            isInverted = __CFCSetIsInverted(theSet);
            return (CFUniCharIsMemberOf(theChar, __CFCSetBuiltinType(theSet)) ? !isInverted : isInverted); 
        }

        isAnnexInverted = __CFCSetAnnexIsInverted(theSet);

        if ((annexPlane = __CFCSetGetAnnexPlaneCharacterSetNoAlloc(theSet, plane)) == NULL) {
            if (!__CFCSetHasNonBMPPlane(theSet) && __CFCSetIsRange(theSet)) {
                isInverted = __CFCSetIsInverted(theSet);
                length = __CFCSetRangeLength(theSet);
                return (length && __CFCSetRangeFirstChar(theSet) <= theChar && theChar < __CFCSetRangeFirstChar(theSet) + length ? !isInverted : isInverted);
            } else {
                return (isAnnexInverted ? true : false);
            }
        } else {
            theSet = annexPlane;
            theChar &= 0xFFFF;
        }
    }

    isInverted = __CFCSetIsInverted(theSet);

    switch (__CFCSetClassType(theSet)) {
        case __kCFCharSetClassBuiltin:
            result = (CFUniCharIsMemberOf(theChar, __CFCSetBuiltinType(theSet)) ? !isInverted : isInverted);
            break;

        case __kCFCharSetClassRange:
            length = __CFCSetRangeLength(theSet);
            result = (length && __CFCSetRangeFirstChar(theSet) <= theChar && theChar < __CFCSetRangeFirstChar(theSet) + length ? !isInverted : isInverted);
            break;

        case __kCFCharSetClassString:
            result = ((length = __CFCSetStringLength(theSet)) ? (__CFCSetBsearchUniChar(__CFCSetStringBuffer(theSet), length, theChar) ? !isInverted : isInverted) : isInverted);
            break;

        case __kCFCharSetClassBitmap:
            result = (__CFCSetCompactBitmapBits(theSet) ? (__CFCSetIsMemberBitmap(__CFCSetBitmapBits(theSet), theChar) ? true : false) : isInverted);
            break;

        case __kCFCharSetClassCompactBitmap:
            result = (__CFCSetCompactBitmapBits(theSet) ? (__CFCSetIsMemberInCompactBitmap(__CFCSetCompactBitmapBits(theSet), theChar) ? true : false) : isInverted);
            break;

        default:
            CFAssert1(0, __kCFLogAssertion, "%s: Internal inconsistency error: unknown character set type", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // We should never come here
            return false; // To make compiler happy
    }

    return (result ? !isAnnexInverted : isAnnexInverted);
}
```

So we can follow along, and figure out what's going on. Unfortunately we have to bust out our x86_64 assembly skills to do it. But fear not, for I have done this for you already, because apparently this is what I do for fun on a Friday night.

A helpful thing to have is the data structure:

```
struct __CFCharacterSet {
    CFRuntimeBase _base;
    CFHashCode _hashValue;
    union {
        struct {
            CFIndex _type;
        } _builtin;
        struct {
            UInt32 _firstChar;
            CFIndex _length;
        } _range;
        struct {
            UniChar *_buffer;
            CFIndex _length;
        } _string;
        struct {
            uint8_t *_bits;
        } _bitmap;
        struct {
            uint8_t *_cBits;
        } _compactBitmap;
   } _variants;
   CFCharSetAnnexStruct *_annex;
};
```

We'll need to know what the heck `CFRuntimeBase` is, too:

```
typedef struct __CFRuntimeBase {
    uintptr_t _cfisa;
    uint8_t _cfinfo[4];
#if __LP64__
    uint32_t _rc;
#endif
} CFRuntimeBase;
```

And guess what! There are also some constants that we'll need.

```
enum {
        __kCFCharSetClassTypeMask = 0x0070,
            __kCFCharSetClassBuiltin = 0x0000,
            __kCFCharSetClassRange = 0x0010,
            __kCFCharSetClassString = 0x0020,
            __kCFCharSetClassBitmap = 0x0030,
            __kCFCharSetClassSet = 0x0040,
            __kCFCharSetClassCompactBitmap = 0x0040,
    // irrelevant stuff redacted
};
```

We can then break on `CFCharacterSetIsLongCharacterMember` and log the structure:

```
supersetA.contains(UnicodeScalar(128518)!)

(lldb) po [NSData dataWithBytes:$rdi length:48]
<21b3d2ad ffff1d00 90190000 02000000 00000000 00000000 06f60100 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000>
```

Based on the structs above, we can figure out what this character set is made of. In this case, the relevant part is going to be the first byte of `cfinfo` from `CFRuntimeBase`, which are bytes 9-12. The first byte of this, `0x90` contains the type information for the character set. It needs to be `AND`ed with `__kCFCharSetClassTypeMask`, which gets us `0x10`, which is `__kCFCharSetClassRange`.

For this line:

```
supersetB.contains(UnicodeScalar(128518)!)
```

the structure is:

```
(lldb) po [NSData dataWithBytes:$rdi length:48]
<21b3d2ad ffff1d00 a0190000 02000000 00000000 00000000 9066f000 01000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000>
```

This time byte 9 is `0xa0`, which `AND`ed with the mask is `0x20`, `__kCFCharSetClassString`.

At this point the Monty Python cast are screaming "Get On With It!", so let's go through the source for `CFCharacterSetIsLongCharacterMember` and see what's going on.

Skipping past all the `CF_OBJC_FUNCDISPATCHV` crap, we get to this line:

```
if (plane) {
```

This obviously evaluates to true in both cases. Next test:

```
if (__CFCSetIsBuiltin(theSet)) {
```

This evaluates to false in both cases, since neither type was `__kCFCharSetClassBuiltin`, so we skip that block.

```
isAnnexInverted = __CFCSetAnnexIsInverted(theSet);
```

In both cases, the `_annex` pointer was null (see all the zeros at the end of the structure), so this is `false`.

This test will be `true` for the same reason:

```
if ((annexPlane = __CFCSetGetAnnexPlaneCharacterSetNoAlloc(theSet, plane)) == NULL) {
```

taking us to:

```
if (!__CFCSetHasNonBMPPlane(theSet) && __CFCSetIsRange(theSet)) {
```

The `__CFCSetHasNonBMPPlane` macro checks `_annex`, so that's false. The emoji, of course, is not in the BMP plane, so this actually seems wrong for *both* cases, even the one that was returning the correct result.

`__CFCSetIsRange` checks if our type is `__kCFCharSetClassRange`, which is only true the first time. So this is our point of divergence. The second invocation of this, which produces the incorrect result, returns on the next line:

```
return (isAnnexInverted ? true : false);
```

And since the annex is `NULL`, causing `isAnnexInverted` to be false, this returns false.

As for how to fix it... well, I can't. But now we know why it happened. From what I can tell, the main problem is that the `_annex` field isn't being filled when the character set is created, and since the annex seems to be used to keep track of characters in non-BMP planes, I think it ought to be present for both of the character sets. Incidentally, this information will probably be helpful in a bug report should you decide to [file one](http://bugreporter.apple.com) (I'd file it against CoreFoundation, since that's where the actual issue is).

Comment: You my friend… are a legend! You went deep on that one! I'll get the bug report fired off!